# ReactJS -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have App.js with products and cart.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProductGrid from './components/ProductGrid';
import CartTable from './components/CartTable';
import { fetchProducts } from './state/product/actions';
import { fetchCart } from './state/cart/actions';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProducts();
    this.props.fetchCart();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isProductLoading,
      products,
      cart,
    } = this.props;

    if(isProductLoading) {
      return <h2>loading...</h2>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Shop application!</h1>
        <ProductGrid
          products={products}
        />
        <h1>Cart</h1>
        <CartTable
          cart={cart}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const getProductById = (products, productId) => products.find(p => p._id === productId);

const populateCartItems = (c, p) => ({
  ...c,
  items: c.items.map(i => ({
    ...i,
    product: getProductById(p, i.productId),
  })),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isProductLoading: state.product.isLoading,
  products: state.product.products,
  cart: populateCartItems(state.cart.cart, state.product.products),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchProducts,
  fetchCart,
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Problem is with the populate of cart and products objects.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.table`
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #DDD;
  }
`;

const CartTable = ({ cart }) => (

  <Wrapper>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
        <th>Item Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {cart.items.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.productId}>
          <td>{item.product.name}</td>
          <td>{}</td>
          <td>{item.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </Wrapper>
);

CartTable.propTypes = {
  cart: PropTypes.shape({
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      product: PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      }).isRequired,
      productId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      quantity: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    })).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default CartTable;
```

When passing cart object to CartTable, I get error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
  30 | <tbody>
  31 |   {cart.items.map(item => (
  32 |     <tr key={item.productId}>
> 33 |       <td>{item.product.name}</td>
  34 |       <td>{}</td>
  35 |       <td>{item.quantity}</td>
  36 |     </tr>
```

I'm quite sure the cart object is working fine in App.js (tested with console.log) but after it has passed to CartTable, populated product object is not found.

Comment: will it be item.product.name or item.productName?

Comment: try to console.log(item.product) to see if thats undefined

Comment: Shubman: the product object has  "_id", "picture", "name" and "price" so I think product.name should be right.

Comment: `item.product` is undefined. Are you sure that all the items' product are set?

Comment: according to error your product is undefined

Comment: The first cart object in list doesn't have any product object so the error might be it

Object
items:Array(3)
0:
{productID: "5b60dde894f25795a04e0d44", quantity: 3, product: undefined}
1:
product:{_id: "5b60dde859f6e51b8354e102", picture: "http://placehold.it/1000x400", name: "eu nisi ut", price: 10.8}
productId:"5b60dde859f6e51b8354e102"
quantity:5

Comment: <td>{item.product? item.product.name : 'xyz'}</td> try this and see if it works or not

Comment: Shubham: The problem is the first cart object on the list doesn't have any product object in it. I try to figure how to empty that list.

Comment: That is why I asked you to try that. It will handle that issue. Its gonna check first whether there is any product available or not and if available then it will render its name other wise some garbage value and you can easily refactor this according to your will. But ideally when you add something to cart it must have one product associated with it

Answer (score 4):

You're not validating your data before trying to render it. A simple fix for the problem would be to change your map function into:

```
{cart.items && !isProductLoading ? cart.items.map(item => (
  <tr key={item.productId ? item.productId : null}>
    <td>{item.product.name ? item.product.name : ''}</td>
    <td>{}</td>
    <td>{item.quantity ? item.quantity : null}</td>
  </tr>
)) : null}
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be two possibilities
1. Your variable name is not correct or
2. Check for item is not empty and then you print something like below one

`cart.items ? cart.items.map(your code)`